# Accessing Connection Received IP

Tags: c#, tcp, connection

I'm slightly struggling on something that is probably really simple but here goes.

I have a method called runServer. Everything is all working in it. I also have another method called logRequest. I want to be able to access a variable I set within runServer. What would be the best way?

```
static void runServer()
{
//Everything is working here but the variable/function I want to access is:
string clientIP = connection.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();
}

static void logRequest()
{
// What I want to do is access the string I created in runServer and use it here.
Console.WriteLine(clientIP);
}
```

I have debugged it and it's all working fine. It does give out an IP address but I want to be able to print that IP address on the console. The runServer just contains TcpListeners, etc. Basic code to run the server. All I want to do is access that string within that method.

I can't really move the variable clientIP out of the method as that is where the connection is.

```
static void runServer()
        {
            TcpListener listener;
            Socket connection;
            NetworkStream socketStream;
            try
            {
                listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 43);
                listener.Start();
                Console.WriteLine("Server Started Listening.");
                while (true)
                {
                    connection = listener.AcceptSocket();
                    string clientIP = connection.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();
                    socketStream = new NetworkStream(connection);
                    doRequest(socketStream);
                    socketStream.Close();
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: add a getter that simply returns the string.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck i've added the full code for the runServer method. How would I approach on doing that? As the connection is opened and closed within that while loop.

Comment: your problem is a lot bigger, how and when is this logger of yours going to run ? You have an endless loop in your runserver and I don't think you have clue about what a thread is.

Comment: Who calls `logRequest()`? With so little information to go on, it's impossible to say what the best way of getting the information to flow from one method to the other would be. Philip might be right about the rest of the code, but we can still focus on the immediate need. However, that can be done only if you provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that clearly illustrates and provides sufficient context for your question.